# How to determine MySQL queries per day?

Tags: mysql

I'm investigating the big switch from MySQL to a NoSQL DBaaS and I've run into an issue trying to forecast expenses. Essentially, I can't figure out how many queries my current MySQL server handles per day to try and estimate the number of requests I'll be using with [Cloudant](http://www.cloudant.com), which charges $0.015 per 100 PUTs, POSTs, and DELETEs and $0.015 per 500 GETs and HEADs.

I've found a lot of information about using [SHOW STATUS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-status.html) and [SHOW GLOBAL STATUS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-status.html) to get the stats that MySQL collects on itself, but there's no timeframe reference.

For instance, SHOW GLOBAL STATUS returns the following:

```
Queries                           | 13576675
```

Which is great, except I have no idea the timeframe that wraps that number. 13 million queries when? Per month? Year? Since the beginning of time?

The MySQL docs don't really elaborate too much:

> Queries
>
> The number of statements executed by the server. This variable includes statements executed within stored programs, unlike
>   the Questions variable. It does not count COM_PING or COM_STATISTICS
>   commands. This variable was added in MySQL 5.0.76.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: The `Queries` global status variable is counting everything since the server was last started... which was `SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Uptime';` seconds ago.  Many status variables are cleared with `FLUSH STATUS;` but `Queries` is not, at least in the test servers I confirmed it on just now, which were MySQL 5.5.19 and 5.6.14.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

For SELECTs:

```
show global status like "Com_select";
```

UPDATEs:

```
show global status like "Com_update";
```

INSERTs:

```
show global status like "Com_insert";
```

DELETEs:

```
show global status like "Com_delete";
```

**ALl values are "cumulativ" since MySQL last restart.**

So to get your SELECTs in one hour:

At 9pm:

```
[21:00:00] [DEV\(none)] mysql> show global status like "Com_select";
+---------------+--------+
| Variable_name | Value  |
+---------------+--------+
| Com_select    | 671664 |
+---------------+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

At 10pm:

```
[22:00:00] [DEV\(none)] mysql> show global status like "Com_select";
+---------------+--------+
| Variable_name | Value  |
+---------------+--------+
| Com_select    | 672363 |
+---------------+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

The number of SELECT in the past hour : 672363 - 671664 = **699**

Best Regards

Comment: Thanks @mfouilleul, this is helpful. I'm going to combine this with the duration var and figure out the volume of queries.

Comment: Just to clarify, `show global status like 'Com_%';` commands are for the whole server, right? What would an alternative be in a shared enviroment -- e.g.: to estimate how far we are from `max_questions`/ max Queries Per Hour (QPH) being hit.

Answer (score 15):

I use this view to keep an eye on the number of queries per second, minute, hour and day:

```
create or replace view _dba_query_stats as
select 
  SUBSTRING(VARIABLE_NAME, 5) as query_type, 
  VARIABLE_VALUE as total_count, 
  round(VARIABLE_VALUE / ( select VARIABLE_VALUE from information_schema.GLOBAL_STATUS where VARIABLE_NAME = 'Uptime_since_flush_status'), 2) as per_second,
  round(VARIABLE_VALUE / ((select VARIABLE_VALUE from information_schema.GLOBAL_STATUS where VARIABLE_NAME = 'Uptime_since_flush_status') / (60)))       as per_minute,
  round(VARIABLE_VALUE / ((select VARIABLE_VALUE from information_schema.GLOBAL_STATUS where VARIABLE_NAME = 'Uptime_since_flush_status') / (60*60)))    as per_hour, 
  round(VARIABLE_VALUE / ((select VARIABLE_VALUE from information_schema.GLOBAL_STATUS where VARIABLE_NAME = 'Uptime_since_flush_status') / (60*60*24))) as per_day,
  FROM_UNIXTIME(round(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(sysdate()) - (select VARIABLE_VALUE from information_schema.GLOBAL_STATUS where VARIABLE_NAME = 'Uptime_since_flush_status'))) report_period_start,
  sysdate() as report_period_end,
  TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME((select VARIABLE_VALUE from information_schema.GLOBAL_STATUS where VARIABLE_NAME = 'Uptime_since_flush_status')),'%Hh %im') as report_period_duration
from 
  information_schema.GLOBAL_STATUS 
where 
  VARIABLE_NAME in ('Com_select', 'Com_delete', 'Com_update', 'Com_insert');
```

Sample output:

```
query_type total_count per_second per_minute per_hour per_day report_period_start report_period_end   report_period_duration
DELETE               0          0          0       0        0 2017-04-16 03:46    2017-04-20 22:14:56 114h 28m
INSERT           36595       0.09          5     320     7672 2017-04-16 03:46    2017-04-20 22:14:56 114h 28m
SELECT        14842019      36.02       2161  129656  3111738 2017-04-16 03:46    2017-04-20 22:14:56 114h 28m
UPDATE          189137       0.46         28    1652    39654 2017-04-16 03:46    2017-04-20 22:14:56 114h 28m
```

Comment: This is great. However, I wish I could sort it based on specific database.